# Error when creating using a custom keras layer in a model with two outputs

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I wrote a custom layer to process the results of a `TimeDistributed` Dense layer.

I chose to use a layer rather then post-processing the NN's results because I want to use the processed results for metrics and later as part of the loss function (be advised that currently I do not use the processed results, so I give a loss weight of `0.0` to the output of the custom layer.

I have modified the `train_generator` and `val_generator` to yield the label twice (inside a list), to accommodate the existence of two outputs.

However, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/user/experiments/LSTM/2/S1B.py", line 324, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/experiments/LSTM/2/S1B.py", line 118, in main
    history=model.fit_generator(train_generator(train_list), steps_per_epoch=len(train_list), epochs=30, verbose=1,validation_data=val_generator(val_list),validation_steps=len(val_list),callbacks=callbacks_list)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1211, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 102, in standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ......
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
from os.path import isfile, join
import time
import random



dev_out= open ('dev_out.txt','w')

### CPU option (set to 1 to run on CPU):
if (0):
    import os
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
###


import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed,Lambda, Dropout, Activation,       Layer
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import keras.backend as K

###
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # prevents it from failing when there is no display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

###

name='S1'
model_designation=str(name)+'_'

data_dir='data'


train_val_split=0.2 # portion to be placed in validation


train_control_number=0
val_control_number=0
batch_size = 16



def basic_LSTM(features_num):


    net_input = Input(shape=(None, features_num))
    L=(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True))(net_input)
    #model.add(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True))
    #model.add(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True))

    SoftDense= TimeDistributed(Dense(features_num, activation='softmax'), name='SoftDense')(L)
    Scoring = ScoringLayer(name='Scoring')(SoftDense)
    #Scoring=Dense(features_num, activation='softmax',name='Scoring')(SoftDense)  #FAKE

    model = Model(inputs=[net_input], outputs=[SoftDense,Scoring])

    print(model.summary())
    model.compile(loss={'SoftDense' :'categorical_crossentropy','Scoring': 'categorical_crossentropy'  },
    loss_weights={'SoftDense': 1., 'Scoring': 0.0},
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics={'SoftDense': ['accuracy',my_3D_top_5,my_3D_top_10]})

    return (model)


class ScoringLayer(Layer):  
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScoringLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(ScoringLayer, self).build(input_shape) 

    def call(self, x):
        max_val=K.max(x,axis=2,keepdims=True)   #[0 - seq num; 1 - step in seq; 2 - onehot result]
        #answer=K.dot (x,max_val)
        answer=K.batch_dot (max_val,x)


        #for debug:
        dev_out.write('\nx\n')
        dev_out.write(str(x))
        dev_out.write('\nmax_val\n')
        dev_out.write(str(max_val))
        dev_out.write('\nanswer\n')
        dev_out.write(str(answer))
        dev_out.write('\n***\n')
        ####

        return (answer)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape)    

def main ():
    input_files=glob.glob(join(data_dir,'*npy'))
    data_list,dim=loader(input_files)
    data_list=discard_duplicates(data_list)

    train_list,val_list=data_spliter(data_list)

    train_list=group_data(train_list,batch_size)
    val_list=group_data(val_list,batch_size)

    filepath = "saved-model-"+model_designation+"-{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, save_best_only=False)
    callbacks_list=[checkpoint] 


    model=basic_LSTM(dim)
    history=model.fit_generator(train_generator(train_list), steps_per_epoch=len(train_list), epochs=30, verbose=1,validation_data=val_generator(val_list),validation_steps=len(val_list),callbacks=callbacks_list)
    report(history)

def discard_duplicates(data_list):
    output=[]
    list_of_sizes=[]
    for data in data_list:
        list_of_sizes.append(list(data.shape)[1]) 
    data_list = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(list_of_sizes,data_list), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]


    output.append(data_list[0])

    for i in range (len(data_list)-1):


        if (np.array_equal(data_list[i],data_list[i+1])):
            pass
        else:
            output.append(data_list[i+1])

    print (len(data_list))
    print (len(output))

    random.shuffle(output)
    return (output)


def group_data(data_list,size):  # groups data and elongate it to match
    output=[]
    list_of_sizes=[]
    for data in data_list:
        list_of_sizes.append(list(data.shape)[1]) 

    data_list = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(list_of_sizes,data_list), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]

    while len(data_list)>size:
        this=data_list[:size]
        data_list=data_list[size:]
        combined=(elongate_and_combine(this))
        output.append(combined)


    combined=(elongate_and_combine(data_list))
    output.append(combined)
    random.shuffle(output)

    return (output)

def elongate_and_combine(data_list):

    max_length= (list(data_list[-1].shape)[1]) 
    last_element=list.pop(data_list)
    output=last_element




    stop_codon=last_element[0,(max_length-1),:]
    stop_codon=stop_codon.reshape(1,1,stop_codon.size)

    for data in data_list:
        size_of_data=list(data.shape)[1]
        while size_of_data<max_length:
            data=np.append(data, stop_codon, axis=1)
            size_of_data=list(data.shape)[1]
        output=np.append(output, data, axis=0)


    return (output)


def train_generator(data_list):
    while True:
        global train_control_number
        train_control_number=cycle_throught(len(data_list),train_control_number)
        #print (train_control_number)       
        this=data_list[train_control_number]


        x_train = this [:,:-1,:] # all but the last 1
        y_train = this [:,1:,:] # all but the first 1

        yield (x_train, [y_train,y_train])




def val_generator(data_list):
    while True:
        global val_control_number
        val_control_number=cycle_throught(len(data_list),val_control_number)
        #print (val_control_number)     
        this=data_list[val_control_number]
        x_train = this [:,:-1,:] # all but the last 1
        y_train = this [:,1:,:] # all but the first 1

        yield (x_train, [y_train,y_train]) # double labels for double outputs



def cycle_throught (total,current):
    current+=1
    if (current==total):
        current=0
    return (current)


def loader(input_files):

    data_list=[]

    for input_file in input_files:
        a=np.load (input_file)
        incoming_shape=list(a.shape)
        requested_shape=[1]+incoming_shape
        a=a.reshape(requested_shape)
        #print (a.shape)
        data_list.append(a)



    return (data_list,incoming_shape[-1])


def data_spliter(input_list):
    val_num=int(len(input_list)*train_val_split)
    validation=input_list[:val_num]
    train=input_list[val_num:]

    return (train,validation)


def my_3D_top_5(true, pred):
    features_num=int(list(pred.shape)[-1])

    true = K.reshape(true, (-1, features_num))   
    pred = K.reshape(pred, (-1, features_num))
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(true, pred, k=5)

def my_3D_top_10(true, pred):
    features_num=int(list(pred.shape)[-1])

    true = K.reshape(true, (-1, features_num))   
    pred = K.reshape(pred, (-1, features_num))
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(true, pred, k=10)




def report(history) :


    print(history.history.keys())


    acc = history.history['acc']
    val_acc = history.history['val_acc']

    loss = history.history['loss']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

    acc_5=history.history['my_3D_top_5']
    val_acc_5=history.history['val_my_3D_top_5']

    acc_10=history.history['my_3D_top_10']
    val_acc_10=history.history['val_my_3D_top_10']



    epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))



    axes[0][0].plot(epochs, acc, 'bo', label='Training acc')
    axes[0][0].plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation acc')
    axes[0][0].set_title('Training and validation accuracy')
    axes[0][0].legend()



    axes[0][1].plot(epochs, loss, 'ro', label='Training loss')
    axes[0][1].plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
    axes[0][1].set_title('Training and validation loss')
    axes[0][1].legend()

    axes[1][0].plot(epochs, acc_5, 'go', label='Training acc over top 5')
    axes[1][0].plot(epochs, val_acc_5, 'g', label='Validation acc over top 5')
    axes[1][0].set_title('Training and validation accuracy over top 5')
    axes[1][0].legend()

    axes[1][1].plot(epochs, acc_10, 'mo', label='Training acc over top 10')
    axes[1][1].plot(epochs, val_acc_10, 'm', label='Validation acc over top 10')
    axes[1][1].set_title('Training and validation accuracy over top 10')
    axes[1][1].legend()

    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig('fig_'+name+'.png')   # save the figure to file


start=time.time()   
main()
finish=time.time()

print (str(int(start-finish))+' Seconds.')
```

Checking the printouts of `ScoringLayer` I see that the sizes of the tensors in it are as expected:

```
x
Tensor("SoftDense/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 501), dtype=float32)
max_val
Tensor("Scoring/Max:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32)
answer
Tensor("Scoring/MatMul:0", shape=(?, ?, 501), dtype=float32)
```

So this does not seem to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was not using the right tool for matrix multiplication. 
Specifically, in `ScoringLayer`, I should have used

```
answer=max_val*x
```

instead of using

```
answer=K.batch_dot (max_val,x)
```

This solves the problem.

The new architecture used changes the names used in `history`, so I also had to change my `report`, replacing

```
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']


loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

acc_5=history.history['my_3D_top_5']
val_acc_5=history.history['val_my_3D_top_5']

acc_10=history.history['my_3D_top_10']
val_acc_10=history.history['val_my_3D_top_10']
```

with

```
acc = history.history['SoftDense_acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_SoftDense_acc']

loss = history.history['SoftDense_loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_SoftDense_loss']

acc_5=history.history['SoftDense_my_3D_top_5']
val_acc_5=history.history['val_SoftDense_my_3D_top_5']

acc_10=history.history['SoftDense_my_3D_top_10']
val_acc_10=history.history['val_SoftDense_my_3D_top_10']
```